# PHP How to display some values of multidimensional array with for loop

Tags: php, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I loop through a  multidimensional array to echo the first five values of every "row" as a table. As far as that, it works perfectly:

```
"<table>";
for ($row = 0; $row < $index_number; $row++) {
  echo  "<tr>";
  for ($col = 0; $col < 5; $col++) {
   echo "<td>".$tablevalue[$row][$col]."</td>";
  }
echo "</tr>";
}
echo"</table>";
```

Now I want to display numbers 1 to 3 and then 8 and 9 again. Neither one for loop inside another nor two seperate loops work the way I want them to. 
Thats what I tried so far:

```
echo "<table>";
for ($row = 0; $row < $index_number; $row++) {
  echo  "<tr>";
  for ($col = 0; $col < 3; $col++ && $col2 = 8; $col2 < 10; $col2++) {
   echo "<td>".$tablevalue[$row][$col]."</td>";
  }
echo "</tr>";
}
echo"</table>";
```

Any ideas on how to make it work?

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 1):

For your inner loop just use a conditional, if you have integer indexes starting at 0:

```
foreach($tablevalue[$row] as $col => $val) {
    if($col < 3 || ($col > 7 && $col < 10)) {
        echo "<td>$val</td>";
    }
}
```

However, as you can see `foreach` is much easier for the entire thing:

```
foreach($tablevalue as $row) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($row as $col => $val) {
        if($col < 3 || ($col > 7 && $col < 10)) {
            echo "<td>$val</td>";
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

If you don't have integer indexes starting at 0, then just `foreach(array_values($tablevalue)...` and `foreach(array_values($row)...` or you can slice what you want and `implode`:

```
foreach($tablevalue as $row) {
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo implode("</td><td>", array_slice($row, 0, 3, true) + 
                              array_slice($row, 7, 2, true));
    echo "</td></tr>";
}
```